# Insert query is not working properly

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I m doing the code for the first time. I created a table and a insert query which didn't work - can anyone tell me my mistake?

HTML Form

```
<form action="placeimiorder.php" method="post">
    <select name="opt"></option><optgroup label="Iphone checker">  
        <option value="Full Gsx Report">Iphone Full Gsx Report lock/unlock status and network - 0.40 Credits   
        <option value="Iphone lock/unlock">Iphone lock/unlock status till 4s - 0.05 Credits      </option>
        <option value="uk checkmen">uk checkmend full report - 60.00 Credits    </option>
        </option>
        <optgroup label="UK"> 
            <option value="audi">O2/Tesco uk iphone  3/3gs/4/4s/5 - 20.00 Credits  </option>
            <option value="audi">Three 3 Hutchison Uk all iphone (clean imei) - 25.00 Credits   </option>
            <option value="audi">vodafone all clean (iphone 3 3gs 4 4s and 5) - 30.00 Credits     </option>
            <option value="audi">Vodafone uk iphone 5s/5c (all clean) - 35.00 Credits</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</form> 

<!--Radio buttons-->
Single <input type="radio" name="f1" value="1">
Multi  <input type="radio" name="f1" value="2"><br>
<form>       
    IMEI:* <input type="text"  name="imei" placeholder="ENTER IMEI*">
    Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="ENTER NOTES*">     

    Responsive Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="ENT Responsive Email*"><br><br>


    <input type="submit" class="classname"  value = "submit"> 
</form>
```

And the php code where I think some problem:

```
<?php

include ("sess.php"); 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("jj");


$msg='';
$msg1='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $opt =$_POST["select"]. "-" .
    $f1 =$_POST["single"]. "-" .
    $imei    =$_POST["imei"]. "-" .
    $notes   =$_POST["notes"]. "-" .
    $email      =$_POST["email"];

    $qry = "insert into table (opt,f1,imei,notes,email) values('{$opt}','{$f1}','{$imei}','{$notes}','{$email}')";

    $sql=mysql_query($qry);

    if ($sql)
    {
        $msg1="Record Added";
    }

    else 
    {
        $msg="Error";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Why does the html have 2 opening `<form` tags?

Comment: Please remove one form tag and </form> also which is in between

Comment: The `$_POST[]` contains the name of the html tag and not the tag name. Your select tag's name is "opt" So you `$opt` will be `$_POST['opt']` and not `$_POST['select']` <br><br> Also your submit button doesn't have a name so `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will always return `false`. <br><br> You can refer to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) for tutorial on form handling in php.

Comment: Also, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should seriously consider migration over to the more secure `mysqli_` functions, or PDO.

Comment: my radio buttons are not in line with the label i put ..... wht shuld i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `missing semicolon`(why you concating all post values) after getting all post values also use from field name to get post data must be same as field name you used in form. `Also remove </form> after select`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $opt =$_POST["opt"];
    $f1 =$_POST["f1"];
    $imei =$_POST["imei"];
    $notes =$_POST["notes"];
    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $qry = "insert into table (opt,f1,imei,notes,email) values('$opt','$f1','$imei','$notes','$email')";
    $sql=mysql_query($qry);
    if ($sql) {
        $msg1="Record Added";
    }
    else {
        $msg="Error";
    }
 }
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape your post data

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO user SET 
username ='".$username."',
password ='".$username."',
name     ='".$name."'";


mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```